# better definition of dom elements in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to know if there's a smoother way create this DOM block dynamically:

```
<tr>
     <td>text</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

This function allows me to add a nested tr to my tbody:

```
 function create_row() {
            var row = document.createElement("TR");
            var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
            var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
            var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var text = document.createTextNode(extract_textarea());

            checkbox.type = "checkbox";

            cell1.appendChild(text);
            cell2.appendChild(checkbox);
            row.appendChild(cell1);
            row.appendChild(cell2);

            return row;
        }
```

P.S. I'm new to Javascript so every single tip is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you are creating html table what else you want to know ?

Comment: And the answer is no. Using standard DOM, that is how to create a row with a prompt and an input. jQuery can streamline this somewhat

Comment: If you want suggestions on code improvement, check out [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Exactly what the previous commenters said. If you want to do it in *Vanilla* JS, no that's the best way. Time to [learn some jQuery, friend!](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: thanks everyone, i wanted to focus more on vanilla js since I'd like to understand what's behind JQuery but I guess i can't go deeper with dom stuff...

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the comments here. You can do pretty much everything in vanilla JS with just as much ease as in jQuery (AJAX calls being the exception to that rule). Learn vanilla JS well and you will have a good foundation.

Comment: Using `row.innerHTML` you can get a few less lines : `var row = document.createElement("TR"); row.innerHTML='<td>'+extract_textarea()+'</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td>'; return row;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` on a created `div` to get the HTML elements you want.

```js
function createRow() {
  const
    div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<tr><td>text</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>';
  
  return div.firstElementChild
}

const 
  newRow = createRow(),
  tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
  
tbody.appendChild(newRow);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function create_row() {
   //var row = document.createElement("TR");
   var row = document.createElement("tr");

   //var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
   //var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");

   //var checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
   //var text = document.createTextNode(extract_textarea());

   //checkbox.type = "checkbox";

   //cell1.appendChild(text);
   //cell2.appendChild(checkbox);

   //row.appendChild(cell1);
   row.appendChild(`<td>${extract_textarea()}</td>`);
   //row.appendChild(cell2);
   row.appendChild(`<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>`);


   return row;
}
```